# Topology for beginners

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, functional-analysis, online-resources

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [best book for topology?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology)

Please Suggest some good books on Topology and Functional Analysis.
It would be good if somebody can post links of video lectures related to these.
Thanks in advance!!

Comment: You might want to split this up into two questions; moreover, there may be duplicates of the resulting two questions. I can't imagine that we haven't had a thread on topology books.

Comment: Probably a good start: [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7520/best-book-for-topology) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/903/choosing-a-topology-text) and [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/150556/can-anybody-recommend-me-a-topology-textbook) and [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7512/good-book-for-self-study-of-functional-analysis) and [that](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/141441/please-suggest-a-functional-analysis-book-to-refresh-my-knowledge).

Comment: We've had so many reference requests for topology books that there is a [thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/4335/reference-textbooks-at-one-place) about topology threads.

Comment: @Eugene: Oh shucks, I had to go and search for these threads on my own...

Comment: For videos (and other resources), you could try the web page of Joel Feinstein and his videos on YouTube: http://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/jff/#Teach

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really liked [Topology](http://books.google.no/books/about/Topology.html?id=XjoZAQAAIAAJ&redir_esc=y) by Munkres. It covers a lot of general topology.

For functional analysis I used [Introductory Functional Analysis with Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471504599) by Kreyszig. It is easy to use for beginners, but maybe other books cover more material.

Answer (score 1):

Currently working through Introduction to Topology by Bert Mendelson.  It seems pretty good so far, rather easy.  It is by Dover, so it was very cheap.
I am planning to work through Munkres later.  It appears that Munkres is "the" Topology text book.